# C++ print out objects error

Tags: c++, object

I am getting stuck on print the object Meja1 and Meja2 into class Informasi.
How I can print the object   `Meja1.print_Meja(); and   Meja2.print_Meja();` 
and please advice me how I can write my code into human readable coding style?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

class Inventaris {
private:
    string Jenis;
    string Warna;
    string Keadaan;


public:

        void setInventaris (string a, string u, string g)
    {
        Jenis=a;
        Warna=u;
        Keadaan=g;

    }
       string getJenis()
    {
        return Jenis;
    }

    string getWarna()
    {
        return Warna;
    }

    string getKeadaan()
    {
        return Keadaan;
    }

    void cetak ()
    {

        cout<<"Info Inventaris adalah :"<<endl;
        cout<<"Jenis            : "<<getJenis()<<endl;
        cout<<"Warna            : "<<getWarna()<<endl;
        cout<<"Keadaan      : "<<getKeadaan()<<endl;
     }


};

class Kursi : public Inventaris {
public:

    void print_Kursi(){
    hitung++;
        cout << "Informasi kursi adalah" <<endl;
        cout<<"Jenis            : "<<getJenis()<<endl;
        cout<<"Warna            : "<<getWarna()<<endl;
        cout<<"Keadaan      : "<<getKeadaan()<<endl;
    }
    static int hitung;
    static getHitung()
    {
        return hitung;
    }
};

class Meja : public Inventaris {
public:
    void print_Meja(){

        cout << "Informasi Meja adalah" <<endl;
        cout<<"Jenis            : "<<getJenis()<<endl;
        cout<<"Warna            : "<<getWarna()<<endl;
        cout<<"Keadaan      : "<<getKeadaan()<<endl;
        hitung_meja++;
    }
    static int hitung_meja;
    static getHitung_meja()
    {
        return hitung_meja;
    }

};

class Informasi : public Meja, public Kursi {

public:
    void print_info(){
        cout << "Informasi" <<endl;
        cout << "Jumlah Meja    = " << Meja::getHitung_meja() << endl;
        Meja1.print_Meja(); // how I print object Meja1 and Meja2
        Meja2.print_Meja();
        cout << "Jumlah Kursi    = " << Kursi::getHitung() << endl;
    }

};

int Kursi::hitung = 0;
int Meja::hitung_meja = 0;

int main() {

    Kursi Kursi1;
    Kursi1.setInventaris("Kursi goyang","Merah muda", "Bekas");
    Kursi1.print_Kursi();

    cout << endl;

    Kursi Kursi2;
    Kursi2.setInventaris("Kursi kakek","reyot", "Bekas");
    Kursi2.print_Kursi();

    cout << endl;

    Meja Meja1;
    Meja1.setInventaris("Meja Antik","Coklat tua","Bekas");
    Meja1.print_Meja();

    cout << endl;

    Meja Meja2;
    Meja2.setInventaris("Meja Coffee","Hijau Robek","Bekas");
    Meja2.print_Meja();

    cout << endl;

    Informasi info;
    info.print_info();

}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "print into class"?

Comment: I want to print  Meja2.print_Meja();  Meja1.print_Meja();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed your code and I made `Meja1` and `Meja2` global declarations so they are accessible by `main()` and `Informasi` class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Inventaris {
private:
    string Jenis;
    string Warna;
    string Keadaan;


public:

    void setInventaris(string a, string u, string g)
    {
        Jenis = a;
        Warna = u;
        Keadaan = g;

    }
    string getJenis()
    {
        return Jenis;
    }

    string getWarna()
    {
        return Warna;
    }

    string getKeadaan()
    {
        return Keadaan;
    }

    void cetak()
    {

        cout << "Info Inventaris adalah :" << endl;
        cout << "Jenis            : " << getJenis() << endl;
        cout << "Warna            : " << getWarna() << endl;
        cout << "Keadaan      : " << getKeadaan() << endl;
    }


};

class Kursi : public Inventaris {
public:

    void print_Kursi() {
        hitung++;
        cout << "Informasi kursi adalah" << endl;
        cout << "Jenis            : " << getJenis() << endl;
        cout << "Warna            : " << getWarna() << endl;
        cout << "Keadaan      : " << getKeadaan() << endl;
    }
    static int hitung;
    static int getHitung()   // <--- FIXED!
    {
        return hitung;
    }
};

class Meja : public Inventaris {
public:
    void print_Meja() {

        cout << "Informasi Meja adalah" << endl;
        cout << "Jenis            : " << getJenis() << endl;
        cout << "Warna            : " << getWarna() << endl;
        cout << "Keadaan      : " << getKeadaan() << endl;
        hitung_meja++;
    }
    static int hitung_meja;
    static int getHitung_meja()   // <--- FIXED!
    {
        return hitung_meja;
    }

};

Meja Meja1;   // <--- Global declaration accessible by main() and Informasi
Meja Meja2;   // <--- Global declaration accessible by main() and Informasi

class Informasi : public Meja, public Kursi {

public:
    void print_info() {
        cout << "Informasi" << endl;
        cout << "Jumlah Meja    = " << Meja::getHitung_meja() << endl;
        Meja1.print_Meja();
        Meja2.print_Meja();
        cout << "Jumlah Kursi    = " << Kursi::getHitung() << endl;
    }

};

int Kursi::hitung = 0;
int Meja::hitung_meja = 0;

int main() {

    Kursi Kursi1;
    Kursi1.setInventaris("Kursi goyang", "Merah muda", "Bekas");
    Kursi1.print_Kursi();

    cout << endl;

    Kursi Kursi2;
    Kursi2.setInventaris("Kursi kakek", "reyot", "Bekas");
    Kursi2.print_Kursi();

    cout << endl;

    Meja1.setInventaris("Meja Antik", "Coklat tua", "Bekas");
    Meja1.print_Meja();

    cout << endl;

    Meja2.setInventaris("Meja Coffee", "Hijau Robek", "Bekas");
    Meja2.print_Meja();

    cout << endl;

    Informasi info;
    info.print_info();
}
```

Comment: Yes the code worked and has no error, but the fields about Jenis,Warna,Keadaaan is empty. int the int main(){} I wrote : Meja1.setInventaris("Meja Antik","Coklat tua","Bekas"); and Meja2.setInventaris("Meja Coffee","Hijau Robek","Bekas");, what I want is to print the Meja1.print_Meja and meja2.print_Meja. or I just to write Meja::print_Meja("Meja Coffee","Hijau Robek","Bekas"); ?

Comment: In your code, you didn't remove the local declaration of Meja1 and Meja2 inside main(). Remove them and you're good to go.

Comment: You are right, the code is working as well. Can you tell me why the Meja Meja1;   // <--- Global declaration accessible by main() and Informasi
Meja Meja2;   // <--- Global declaration accessible by main() and Informasi must write outside main() ?

Comment: It's to make Meja1 and Meja2 available to ANY function and class in your file. When they're declared within a function/class, main() in your original code, only that function/class can access the contents of those classes. The location of the declaration of variables dictates their scope, or where you can use them.